# Is there a way to find JS-Plugins in the DOM-Tree programmatically?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on a Web-App where users should be enabled to enter a lot of tabular data in the most convenient way possible.
Therefore I started of with a standard HTML-Table and began applying adding CSS properties and JS functions to it. So for so good. People will be able to drag around cells and duplicate rows on the fly. The latter is causing quite some issues because e.g. date fields that have a jQuery-UI Datepicker Widget enabled will mess up the functions once cloned.

I thought about adding a Pseudo-CSS Class to the cells that have JS associated with to destroy the Plugin-Instances on them and Re-Instantiate the JS upon completion. This brings me to my question:

Is there a way using JS to walk through the DOM-Tree and detect every Instance of any kind of JS-Code/-Plugin (maybe by its Namespace?) so I could attach the mentioned Pseudo-Class to that certain Table-Cell?

Thanks a lot,

Tobias

Comment: i my imagination if i understand you correct, you should instance the libraries on the elements after creating for example don't put date-picker on the "table row" globally rather directly on the cloned element after inserting into the DOM.

Comment: Correct, the problem are cells that are already holding a plugin-instance and are getting cloned. This results in a weird constellation: the new cell gets a new (randomly generated) id, so the plugin fires up but modifies the value within the originating cell.

Comment: yes, i think you have to hook into the clone process to attach the libary functionallity directly onto the created element... not with a class or something